# How to apply a function between each element of a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list and I want to apply a function between two elements. For example let's imagine the list *[a, b, c, d]*. I need to apply the foo function between all elements of the list two by two. As in combinatorial analysis. So it would look like this: **foo (a, b); foo (a, c); foo (a, d); foo (b, a); foo (b, c); foo (b, d); foo (c, a); foo (c, b); foo (c, d); foo (d, a); foo (d, b) and foo (d, c)**.

I assume that exists a lib or a function thats helpme with this problem.

Comment: Write a *nested loop.* Use your two loop indices in `foo(x,y)`.  See here for inspiration: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_nested_loops.htm

Comment: _I assume that exists a lib or a function thats helpme with this problem._

Yes, they are called loops.

Comment: Nested loops or [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: @glibdud thx! Is that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        if i != j:
            foo(lst[i], lst[j])
```